# With first-of-type in css is working too much good?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have CSS to put the first letter bigger than others :

It works too much lol.
Here my problem :

[image]

Code example :

```css
/*Lettrine*/
.article-content::first-letter,
.article-content p:first-of-type::first-letter
{
    font-size:96px;
}
```

```html
<div class="article-content">
  <p>P1</p>
  <p>P2.</p>
  <div>
    <p>P3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want P3 to get this style.
How i can solve this problem ?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match direct `p` children only:

```css
/*Lettrine*/
.article-content::first-letter,
.article-content > p:first-of-type::first-letter
{
    font-size:96px;
}
```